# What is the adjoint orbit of element of lie algebra?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I was studying paper by GRANT CAIRNS about geodesic basis.
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.2186.pdf There I was about adjoint orbit of element of lie algebra. I only know adjoint representation of lie algebra.  but if
Let Z is a element of a lie algebra g. how do we define the adjoint orbit of Z ?

Comment: Is it not the orbit $\operatorname{Ad}(G)Z$ of $Z$ under the adjoint action of $G$? (If $G$ is a matrix Lie group, $\operatorname{Ad}(g) Z = gZg^{-1}$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take any connected Lie group $G$ with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. (This exists by Lie's third theorem.) The adjoint orbit of an element $Z\in\mathfrak{g}$ is defined by
$$G\cdot Z=\{\mathrm{Ad}_gZ:g\in G\},$$
where $\mathrm{Ad}_g$ is the differential at $1\in G$ of the conjugation map $C_g:G\to G$, $h\mapsto ghg^{-1}$.

It is not difficult to show that if $G_1$ and $G_2$ are two connected Lie groups with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, then $G_1\cdot Z=G_2\cdot Z$ for all $Z\in\mathfrak{g}$. So this is well-defined, independently of the chosen Lie group $G$. The idea of the proof is to show that $\tilde{G}_1\cdot Z=G_1\cdot Z$, where $\tilde{G}_1$ is the universal covering group of $G_1$. Then, use that $\tilde{G}_1=\tilde{G}_2$, which follows since they have the same Lie algebra.